# How can I get the image gallery to change the display image to the thumbnail image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I can this image gallery to change the big image to the thumbnail image? I can't seem to get it to work. I need to get the src attribute of the thumbnail into the value for the big src attribute's value.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSChloe.css">

</head>
<body id = "bodyc">
    <div id = "space1">
    </div>
        <div id = "header">
        <div class="image">
        <img src = "Banner.png" alt= " " width="257" height="43" />
        <h4> text</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "space2"> </div>
        <div id= "menuBack">
            <div id= "menu1"><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p id = "menu2">link</p></a></div>
            <div id= "menu1"><a href="about.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p id = "menu2">link</p></a></div>
            <div id= "select"><a href="photo.html" style="text-decoration:none;">           
            <img src = "back.png" alt = " " width = "257" height = "48" style = "position: absolute; left: -14px; top: -5px;" />
            <p id = "menu2" style = "position: absolute; margin-top: 2%;">Photo Gallery</p></a>
            </div>
            <div id= "menu1"><a href="price.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p id = "menu2">link</p></a></div>
            <div id= "menu1"><a href="testimontials.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p id = "menu2">link</p></a></div>
            <div id= "menu1"><a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><p id = "menu2">link</p></a></div>
            <div id= "menu3"><img src ="photographylogo.png" width = "150" height = "125" /></div> 
        </div>
        <div id = "space3"> </div>
        <div id= "content">
        <div style = "width: 60%; height: 100%; float: left;">
        <img id = "big" src ="test1.png" width = "400" height = "350" style = "margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 8%;" />
        </div>
        <div style = "width: 35%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; float:right;">
        <img id = "thumb1" onclick = "thumbFunc('test2.png');" src = "test2.png" width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb2" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb3" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb4" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb5" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb6" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb7" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb8" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb9" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb10" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb11" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb12" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <br/>
        <img id = "thumb13" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        <img id = "thumb14" src = " " width = "150" height = "100" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function thumbFunc(a)
        {
        document.getElementById("big").setAttribute(src, a);
        }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the way you call your function on your inline on-click:

```
onclick="thumbFunc('test2.png');"
```

to this, so you don't have to put the image path again:

```
onclick="thumbFunc(this.src)"
```

Then, change your javascript:

```
document.getElementById("big").setAttribute(src, a);
```

to this (if you prefer simpler way):

```
document.getElementById("big").src = a;
```

or if you want to still stick with the `setAttribute` method, don't forget to enclose the attribute(src) with the `"` symbol:

```
document.getElementById("big").setAttribute("src", a);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SUhYt/)**

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to remove `;` (except saving a single character).

Comment: @Fabrício Matté Ahh, I see.. Sorry for that, I was raised given the impression of not using that in calling functions in inline event handlers.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any difference in the end. The code you pass into inline handlers is automatically wrapped in a `function(event){}` and assigned as the event handler, so even if you miss the semicolon your code still works as JS does not require explicit semicolons.